# <li> rollover + text

Tags: css, rollover

I have a menu with tiled images w/text under them. See Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/techydude/GF8tS/

Is there a way I can rollover the box and have the text also activate its hover state, and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Instead of using `:hover` on the actual elements, apply it through their common parent, the `li`.

So use

`li:hover .rounded` instead of `.rounded:hover`

and

`li:hover .tileText` instead of `.tileText:hover`

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/DwT8K/1/

Answer (score 0):

Yup http://jsfiddle.net/GF8tS/1/

I modified the CSS, so when the user hovers over the `list-item`, it would modify the CSS of the `.tileText` and the `.rounded`

```
li:hover .rounded {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(193, 232, 0, .75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(193, 232, 0, .75);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(193, 232, 0, .75);
}
li:hover .tileText {
color:#C3EA00;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: yeah.. I dont really care about people on IE6. Thanks!